# In Rails 5, on submitting a form with remote true, I want the controller to execute a javascript, But all the javascript code is rendered as text

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

Here is the form tag:

```
<%= form_tag api_bill_upload_url(:format=> :js), :method=> 'post', :class=> 'form-horizontal', :id=> 'uploadForm',
               :multipart=> 'true', :remote=> 'true', :authenticity_token => true do%>
 <%end%>
```

Here is the action code:

```
def bill_upload
 respond_to do |format|
  format.js {render js: "alert('Hello Rails');"}
  format.html {redirect_to root_url}
 end
end
```

Here is the Development Log:

Started POST "/api/bill_upload.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-01 20:19:47 +0530
Processing by ApiController#bill_upload as JS
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Edit: Looks like it has something to do with file input, when i upload a file, the script is rendered as text but when i submit the form without any file, the script works correctly.

Comment: Previously, you couldn't send a multipart form (file upload) via remote=true. And, apparently, you still can't. That's where libraries like jqueryFileUpload come in.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem like this while uploading images. I think you might be using carrier wave to upload files.I added a little fix to that problem, what I did was I just used the form in a modal and after that when I uploaded images using modal it went as js format.  It's the multipart which causes the trouble. I think you can use a modal or so to upload and you will get as Js in action.